# Evaluating the predictive power of a model in comparison to a random number generator

Tags: statistics, random

I would like to know if there is any way of quantifying the performance of the predictive power of a model in comparison to say a random number generator... for example, let's say with have two models:

Model A is able to predict the correct outcome 73% of the times as opposed to a random number generator that can do that only 19% of the times.
Model B is able to predict the correct outcome 78% of the times as opposed to a random number generator that can do that 38% of the times.

Is there anyway of quantifying the performance of both of these models relative to random number generator in a simple number?

Comment: There is an extremely strong case for a negative answer. In one sentence: if it is a binary classification (for instance), do you have as many negative and positive (0 and 1) samples, and are you more impacted by false positive (negative parts that you label 1), or false negative (positive parts that you label 0)?

Comment: If your answer is $50\%-50\%$ and both classes are completely interchangeable, you can just take the accuracy. This is a very rare case in the real world, and a good practice is to always give some thought on how your "performance" actually should be measured, and not take the first loss that you find

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The outcome can only be a false negative or a true positive. I am tryting to quantify the performance of the models only in relation to the random number generator, so basically how much more accurate they are at predicting a true positive than randomly assigning true positives... I hope what I wrote makes sense...

Comment: Basically I want a number that can describe the predictive power of these Models vis-à-vis the random number generator...